# Deploy NodeJS application with IIS

Tags: node.js, express, iis

I would like to deploy internally my Node application build with Express on IIS, but I don't know how.

Does anyone have an idea or can redirect me to a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot host your Node.js application on IIS. You can use IIS as revers proxy for your Node.js application.

Then you would start your Node.js application on your Node.js and setup IIS to rout requests to your Node.js application hosted on Node.js.

Tutorial for something like this can be found [here](https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b)

Comment: Years ago HttpPlatformHandler was created to serve such apps on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ So, surprised to see an answer like this.